# Use SSH to connect to Git on a server

Tags: wordpress, bash, git, ssh, terminal

Any help here would be great.

I've connected to a server which hosts a Wordpress site using SSH, using git bash from my local machine.

My aim, is to connect my visual studio and directory where I'm going to do local dev work to the server.

The issue that I'm having is:

I cannot find where the git repo on the server is?

I've ran:

```
[20-07-15 22:50]XXXXXXXXXXXXX git version
git version 2.7.4
```

So git is there:

but after running:

```
[20-07-15 22:50]XXXXXXXXXXXXXX git init
/home/wp/.git: Permission denied
```

So I'm a little lost - how to push updates to this server via git - as I cannot seem to find the remote address for the server?

(this might be a issue in my workflow? or how I'm approaching the task - any help would be really appreciated) -

Normally what I would do is - init git from the C-panel / get the remote address / add that as a remote from my local machine and push updated - but i haven't done so using SSH before via my terminal.

Thank you in advance,
Wally

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I found the answer via trial and error

1. When you SSH into a directory, it is in the root of the folder i.e.

   /home/wp

I did not have permission to git init in this folder -

2. to source the Wordpress folder you need to move down the file tree using bash commands i.e.

Using `cd XX/XX/XX`

```
/home/wp/disk/wordpress
```

3. now that you are in the WordPress directory, you can git init

--

Im still yet to work out the next step but will update once I do:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to somehow set up a directory and init it... like you were trying to do on the second command that you showed there. There you have a permissions problem, it's not a git problem. So, let's suppose you solve it and you end up creating the repo in `/home/wp/blahblah` (cause I see that it's not a bare repo but a full repo that you are trying to create).

Then, from your local computer you need to set up a remote... something like:

```
git remote add the-remote wp@the-server-ip:/home/wp/blahblah
```

Then you should be able to fetch and so on. Not specifying how to set up ssh certificates and so on to avoid having to provide the password every time because it is outside of the scope of the question and you can find plenty of answers about how to do that.

Comment: Thank you for the feed back - Do you think there is a way to pull this directory as it is into my local device - I can see now the issue is permission based, but the workflow I was hoping to use was - pull the Wordpress content to the local machine, make adjustments and then push it back with updates / I might be going about this the wrong way? -- could you suggest how to update Wordpress on a server that doesn't use c-panel? (sorry if that's an odd question) - thanks